# Oracle vs. MySql database. Which is faster and more efficient?

Tags: mysql, oracle

we are having trouble getting http://nabacar.com to search fast and thought we may need to change to an oracle database to fix the problem.  Can you advise?  we are currently using mysql database and thought that might be what the problem is.  actually, if you go to http://nabacar.com/index.php?menu=find_car and try to get it to search all cars it is fine, but if you try to narrow your search it really takes a long time.  Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: OK, download, install Oracle, migrate the database and see if it's any faster.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you are constructing a poorly performing query?  Unless you are working on large amounts (terabytes) of data, it's highly unlikely that switching DBMS alone will solve your problems...

Comment: try to index data, optimize or redesign queries first before changing database

Comment: Not enough information to give advice. Why do you think the database is the problem? How much data is there? Have you tried tuning the query, tuning the schema, or upgrading hardware?

Comment: Narrowed the search down and it still wasn't slow... also, probably not your database engine causing issues.

Comment: Mysql is a special kind of bitch when you try to 1-to-many join with order by and like or order by and limit, been there before, cant say i liked it.

Comment: For a certain simple test case, about 1M rows, oracle is much faster (10+ times) than mysql.

Answer (score 6):

Thinking about changing the RDBMS is usually the last thing one can do when looking for optimization.

Instead one, in my opinion, should start with analyzing the actual queries web application performs - and look for bottlenecks closely. There's plenty of advice in the Net about how to do it; I suggest checking [this excellent site](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) and [this article](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-sql-tips-to-speed-up-your-database), just for beginning. )

Comment: Don't forget to also ask yourself "For what purpose do I execute these queries?". Your client code could do 3 perfectly optimized queries and process their result for some purpose, but rewriting things to have 1 single query for this same purpose might be even faster/lighter then.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned in comments, unless you are dealing with many terabytes of data, your DBMS probably isn't the real issue here.  Most likely you can increase performance by improving your queries or table indexes.

Also, for something like search, you can often increase performance dramatically by using a purpose-built system like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) rather than hitting your database directly.

Finally, I would recommend you post another question with specific queries that are running slow and more details about your database structure and indexes.  We would be able to give you much more specific and helpful answers that way.